Bringing hair styling powder onto a plane
I'm flying from Italy to Switzerland just with hand luggage. I have a hair powder which could possibly look like coke to someone. Is this going to be any problem? I'm not sure if it's going to show up as something organic on a ct scan and I don't want to go through the headache of getting searched further. Here is the link to the powder

There are so many things that look like coke but their chemical analysis under the CT machine could easily reveal that they are NOT a coke. So, if you genuinely have a powder, which is a common thing to keep in a hand luggage, you should not worry. However, you should make sure the volume/weight does not exceed from the permitted limit, which from the link you shared seems perfectly okay to carry in your hand luggage.
